# No signature of method [] is applicable for argument types

Tags: postgresql, grails, groovy

Hi i have this service:

```
def insertAction(int Id, String Name){
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        sql.execute("INSERT INTO  mn (id, name) VALUES ($Id,$Name)")
    }
```

this controller:

```
def save() {
       println params
       [contact: contactListService.insertAction(params.id,params.Name)]
        redirect action: "create"
```

And when i create a new entry i get this error

No signature of method: contactlist.ContactListService.insertAction() is applicable for argument types: (null, java.lang.String) values: [null, das] Possible solutions: insertAction(int, java.lang.String), listAction()

Comment: Don't use capital letters for variable names or parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, like the error suggests.
You defined your first parameter to be `int`, but you give it `null`.
`null` can be taken for any object, but not for a primitive type like `int`.
Either change your method parameter to be an object like `Integer` (or `def` to not specify an explicit type) and check for `null` inside your method, or check your `params` before you give its values to the method.

Comment: Well i changed some stuff but now i get this  No signature of method: contactlist.ContactListService.insertAction() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [3, h] Possible solutions: insertAction(int, java.lang.String), listAction()

Comment: Well, still just as the error suggests. You have defined your method to expect an `int` and a `String`, but you supply it two `String`s. Either transform your first parameter to int before giving it to the method with `params.id as int` or change your method signature to `String, String` or `def, String`.

Comment: I changed is and get the error i was expecting. id is bigint in my database. ERROR: column "id" is of type bigint but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: `$Id` -> `${Id as long}`

Comment: that fixed it thanks. but i still dont understand why this happened

Comment: Why not? What don't you understand?

Comment: why the controller expects a String while the id collumn in db is bigint.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "controller". If you mean `insertAction`, then because you defined it as that now because you gave in a `String`. Why that is the case I cannot tell you, as you do not show enough code for that. Btw. if the answer solved your issue, please accept and upvote it.